# Always Auto Increment ID is 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have page to user to enter there information Like Name and address and phone number but i' hiding the UserID column in the webpage in the view page.So My page contain below information.
Name = Textbox,
Address=Textbox

When I run the page 
Displaying above two textbox 
After enter value
Name = xxxxx
Address=california
When i click button When i debug user id showing is 0

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["infinity"].ConnectionString))
        {
            List<Plantation> studentlist = new List<Plantation>();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc_UpdatePlantation ", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlantationID", viewPlantationModel.PlantationID); // here always 0
```

how can fix it this one i not show to user id  to user in the web page using mvc view but i have column in the database that auto increment id

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately I don't think anyone could answer this question with the information given. Please see [ask] for tips on how to attract useful answers.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Do you need user identity number to be database generated and auto incremented?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not using hidden variable of ID on view so please write below code on your view.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ID)
```